# Polars dataframe to MS SQL date convention error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyarrow, python-polars

```py
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

#Database
mssql_db1 = '' #Read From
mssql_db2 = '' #Write to
query = 'Select *'

polar_df = pl.read_database(query,mssql_db1 ,partition_num=5)
#after some Transform....

print(polar_df)
#My Polar data looks like this:

------|----------|-----|
id    |DATE      |Var  |
------|----------|-----|
str   |date      |i64  |
------|----------|-----|
ID1   |2023-04-16|99999|
------------------------

polar_df.write_database(table_name="Table1", connection_uri=mssql_db2, if_exists='replace')
```

This return error:
**NotImplementedError: dt.tz is not supported for date32[day][pyarrow]**

But when i cast back to pandas, it work:

```py
df = polar_df.to_pandas()
#if i skip this line it still worked
df["DATE"] = df["DATE"].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).to_pydatetime()) 
df.to_sql(name='Table1',con=mssql_db2,if_exists='replace')
```

How do i fix this if i want pure polars solutions ? Thanks

**[Update]**

This worked for polar to my SQL database , but it created unwanted timestamps

```py
polar_df= polar_df.with_columns(
    polar_df["DATE"].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).to_pydatetime(), return_dtype=pl.Object)
)
print(polar_df)

------|-------------------|-----|
id    |DATE               |Var  |
------|-------------------|-----|
str   |datetime[μs]       |i64  |
------|-------------------|-----|
ID1   |2023-04-16 00:00:00|99999|
---------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The polars `write_database` method just converts to pandas anyway.  [Here's](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/py-polars/polars/dataframe/frame.py#L3153-L3220) the source snippet:

```
        self.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True).to_sql(
            name=table_name, con=engine, if_exists=if_exists, index=False
        )
```

I notice that in your demonstration you had this line...

```
df["DATE"] = df["DATE"].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).to_pydatetime())
```

What happens if you skip that line? I suspect you had a similar error before including that conversion.

Possible fixes:

1. Keep manually converting to pandas and converting to a python date.
2. Use `engine='adbc'` in [write_database](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.write_database.html#polars.DataFrame.write_database). I don't know if adbc supports SQL Server yet so this might be a dead end
3. Write your own inserts with `sqlalchemy` (or whatever library you like) and `df.iter_rows()`
4. You can convert your date column to strings.

   df.with_columns(DATE=pl.col('DATE').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

Comment: even i skip that line, the pandas way still works ; I changed the 'date' type to 'datetime[μs]' in Polars and it worked somehow